# Where is the biggest New Years Eve party in Manila?

Tags: public-holidays, nightlife, manila

What is Manila's equivalent of New York's Times Square, or Singapore's "Siloso Beach Party" on Sentosa island? If I'm in Manila and I want to be with the largest number of people, where should I go for New Years?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the best parties around Manila this year are at The Palace Pool Club Manila (Bonifacio Global City) and at Chaos Nightclub Manila (City Of Dreams) - source: [The 5 Best New Year's Eve 2017 Parties in Manila and Cebu](https://www.ph2nite.com/magazine/nightlife/the-5-best-new-years-eve-2017-parties-in-manila-and-cebu/).

Checkout this handy website to stay updated with Manila nightlife best parties and events.

[Ph2nite - The Guide to Manila Nightlife](https://www.ph2nite.com/manila/)